# i18n doesn't work at production environment on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, internationalization

I have seen more than one hundred posts about i18n issues and no solution seems to solve my problem.

I have an app running with Django 1.3.1 and it works Fine at my develop machine. But when I bring to **heroku** nothing happens. The files are not translated at all. It seems that the locale folder in my project is not being found.

Locale folder is at my project level and this is my settings:

```
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', ugettext('English')),
    ('pt-br', ugettext('Portuguese')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "locale"),
)
```

Locale folder follows this structure:

```
locale
    pt_BR
        LC_MESAGES
            django.mo
            django.po
```

Comment: you could use a mini middleware that quickly sets the language of your choice, I did it and proved that my files were ok and was something else:
[language middleware](http://pastebin.com/F2fbkEG8)

Comment: I took off the English language and set only Portuguese. My whole application stayed in English but Django Administration was working fine!

Comment: Django docs says that if I only use my native language and set it in LANGUAGE_CODE, middlewares are not required. So, doesn't it prove that the files are not being found?
Also, I checked at the server, and the files were there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sample above you wrote  `LC_MESAGES` instead of  **`LC_MESSAGES`** (notice the double S), I believe this very well could be your issue.

If not then read on!

I had this issue (again!) recently, and the answer was found in [this part of the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations)

I suspect you have the same issue since your "admin" app was translated but not your own (project) app.

It seems that Django is looking for your translations like so:

> 1. The directories listed in LOCALE_PATHS have the highest precedence,
>      with the ones appearing first having higher precedence than the ones
>      appearing later.
> 2. Then, it looks for and uses if it exists a locale
>      directory in each of the installed apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS. The
>      ones appearing first have higher precedence than the ones appearing
>      later.
> 3. Finally, the Django-provided base translation in
>      django/conf/locale is used as a fallback.

With the settings you described above, you must make sure your tree looks something like this (with the most important being settings.py is in the dir above the 'locale' dir):

```
+-project_top/
  |
  +-project_app/
  | |
  | +-locale/
  | | |
  | | +-pt_BR/
  | |   |
  | |   +-LC_MESSAGES/
  | |     |
  | |     +-django.po
  | |  
  | +-settings.py
  |
  +-manage.py
```

Comment: In my case the solution was _with the most important being settings.py is in the dir above the 'locale' dir_ and adding it's path to the **LOCALE_PATHS**. This is the only configuration I was able to get to work on Heroku. I don't know if it is the same for the other servers.

Answer (score 6):

I've found different platforms prefer different language folder names.  I was pulling my hair out on my development system (Mac OS X) because '/pt-br/LC_MESSAGES/' wouldn't work, even though makemessages created the folders that way and compile messages worked fine too.  It finally sprang to life once I renamed the languages as '/pt_br/LC_MESSAGES/' (notice the underscore).

Migrating the same project to production (Ubuntu), it stopped working again, I tried everything under the Sun thinking the folder names must already be correct since they work on my dev. machine.  I finally, out of desperation tried uppercasing the country component like '/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/', and, boom, it started working again.

Even thought my Python and Django and all of my various Python/Django libraries and apps were (by design) identical versions, I suspect that each system has different versions/builds of gettext beneath them, which is likely responsible for the differences.

Comment: If you're in 2018 and still fighting this (specifically for zh_Hans / zh_Hant), there's more to it. If you're developing on mac (which is case insensitive), everything will work. As soon as you deploy this elsewhere  in my case Heroku / docker running linux), translations won't be found if your path is named `zh_Hans` or any variation of it. Make sure you use `zh_hans`/`zh_hant` as your folder name. You might need to use git mv so that if picks up the change ;)

Answer (score 4):

By default, compiled translation files (`*.mo`) are ignored by git. Verify that you have this exception removed from your `.gitignore` file.

If that is the case, remove this exception, add these files to git, commit and push to Heroku to have them available to the app in Heroku.

Comment: .mo files are no source files. They shouldn't be part of a repository.

Comment: So then what would be the alternative? Should it be compiled at the server?

Comment: @JOANNM: It is your decision what you have in git. So if you deploy some easy web with `git push/pull`, remove .mo from .gitignore. Or you can use different deployment tool. Or you can `compilemessages` in production but I don't think that this is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your language settings are wrong.

It should be like:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('zh', 'China'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ja', 'Japanese'),
)
```

Next, check if the domain in your cookie settings are correct.

I had the same problem and thought Heroku's virtual environment would never support i18n, but finally found out that my 'django-language' value in the session cookie belongs to my local testing server '0.0.0.0:5000'.

After changing the settings, my translations done on the local server worked out of the box.

Comment: 'zh' is not accepted as language code. You need to use 'zh-cn' or other aliases listed here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, directories with a "-" or "_" within the name are not correctly addressed. I solved the issue customizing the url to be be a 2-chars code. This can be done creating an alias:

```
from django.conf import global_settings, locale
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'pt': {
        'fallback': ['pt-br'],
    },
}
LANG_INFO = dict(locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to highlight a comment by @msaad above. If you're developing on Mac OS X and your translation directory is all lower case then change it from es_es -> es_ES and redeploy. This solved the problem for me. On OS X the system is case insensitive, but on linux systems it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't answer related to Heroku, but just to have most possibilities collected:

I have Debian 10 development and Debian 10 virtual server in production. Everything was ok in development, i18n failed in production.

Reason: I needed **`apt install gettext`**.

And in addition, be sure that **.mo files are in git** and not disabled by .gitignore (this answer is here already),