# Django on Heroku: customizing django.po

Tags: django, heroku, internationalization, mezzanine

I used to run Mezzanine on Heroku. Recently, I need to customize some data in the django.po. As Mezzanine is installed from requirements.txt, how do I upload my own `django.po` in order to overwrite Django's standard `django.po`?

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246545/i18n-doesnt-work-at-production-enviroment-on-heroku/14927172#14927172

Comment: I ended up with forking Mezzanine on Github, customizing it, and then installing the customized version on Heroku. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to override them dynamically while running application.
Here's probably the best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20439571/2466146) that I've seen.