# Django i18n translations not working in production (Heroku)

Tags: django, heroku, django-i18n

My translations are working locally, but in production at Heroku, my site remains in its default language (English) after changing the language.

These are in my `settings.py` file:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')]
```

This is my structure:

```
myproject
├── Procfile
├── locale
│   └── fr
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           ├── django.mo
│           └── django.po
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── settings.py
```

I thought it was a [path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518783/django-1-5-5-displays-original-en-strings-always-does-not-translate) so I SSH'd into my Heroku app and printed `LOCALE_PATHS`:

```py
>>> from myproject.settings import LOCALE_PATHS
>>> print(LOCALE_PATHS)
['/app/locale']
```

And `pwd` in `locale/` returns `pwd
/app/locale`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Isn't it helpful for you? [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246545/i18n-doesnt-work-at-production-environment-on-heroku/14927172)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue:
my `django.mo` file was ignored by `.gitignore` as I use the [default GitHub Python gitignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.mo` files (compiled translations) are not present in the repo, and therefore not packaged to be deployed together with the rest of the application during the Heroku build process.

The possible solutions are to:

1. Add them to the repository
2. Generate `.mo` files during the build

I suggest to generate them during the build, for these reasons:

- It automates compilation, one less manual step
- It will ensure that the translations are always up to date
- The compiled files are not source, and therefore should be in the repository

To generate them, you can use the post compile hook of the Heroku build:

Create a file `bin/post_compile` (no extension, like procfile) with the following line:

```
python ./manage.py compilemessages
```

Optionally you can add the specific language (e.g. `python ./manage.py compilemessages -l nl`)

I got this last part from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096218/6828268) to a similar question.